# Construct normal series from derived series through generating sets

Tags: group-theory, solvable-groups, derived-subgroup

This is from section 2 of the paper "Quantum algorithms for solvable groups" by J. Watrous, where $G$ is a solvable group, and $G = G^{(0)} \rhd G^{(1)} \rhd \cdots \rhd G^{(n)}$ is the derived series of $G$:

---

Now we return to the topic of solvable groups, and review some known facts about solvable groups in the context of black-box groups. First, with respect to any given group oracle, if we are given generators $g_1, . . . , g_m$ of encoding length $n$, it is possible to test whether $G = \langle g_1, . . . , g_m\rangle$ is solvable via a polynomial time (in $nm$) Monte Carlo algorithm. Moreover, the same algorithm can be used to construct (with high probability) generators $g_1^{(j)}, \cdots, g_k^{(j)}$, for $j = 0, \cdots, n$ and where $k = O(n)$, such that $G^{(j)} = \langle g_i^{(j)},\cdots g_k^{(j)}\rangle$ (so that testing solvability can be done by verifying that $g_1^{(n)}, \cdots, g_k^{(n)}$ are each the identity element). At this point we notice (under the assumption that G is solvable) that by relabeling the elements
$$g_1^{(n−1)},\cdots, g_k^{(n−1)}, g_1^{(n−2)},\cdots, g_k^{(n−2)},\cdots, g_1^{(0)}, \cdots, g_k^{(0)}$$
as $h_1,\cdots, h_{kn}$ (in the order given) we have the following. If $H_j = \langle h_1,\cdots, h_j\rangle$ for $j = 0, . . . , kn$, then $\{1\} = H_0 \lhd H_1 \lhd\cdots\lhd H_{kn} = G$. This follows from the fact that $G^{(j)} \lhd G^{(j−1)}$ for each $j$, and further that $G^{(j−1)}/G^{(j)}$ is necessarily abelian.

---

My question is why do we have $\{1\} = H_0 \lhd H_1 \lhd\cdots\lhd H_{kn} = G$. As far as I can understand, $H_0, H_1, \cdots, H_{kn}$ is a chain of subgroups, but why are they normal? I'm not sure where the facts $G^{(j)} \lhd G^{(j−1)}$ and $G^{(j−1)}/G^{(j)}$ is abelian is used to show that this chain of subgroups is normal.

If $H_i = G^{(j)}$ for some $i,j$, then I can convince myself that $H_i \lhd H_{i+1}$, but what about the case where $H_i, H_{i+1} \subseteq G^{(j)}$?

Comment: Note that $G^{(j)}/G^{(j+1)}$ is abelian, so for any $H$ and $K$, $G^{(j+1)}\leq K\leq H\leq G^{(j)}$ implies $K\triangleleft G^{(j)}$ and hence $K\triangleleft H$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why $G^{(j+1)} \leq K \leq H \leq G^{(j)}$ implies that $K \lhd G^{(j)}$?

Comment: The Isomorphism theorems. $K/G^{(j+1)}$ is a subgroup of $G^{(j)}/G^{(j+1)}$, which is abelian. So $K/G^{(j+1)}$ is normal in $G^{(j)}/G^{(j+1)}$. The correspondence/lattice isomorphism theorem tells you subgroups of $G/N$ are in one-to-one, inclusion preserving, normality preserving correspondence with subgroups of $G$ that contain $N$. This is pretty basic, and should be covered well before you study derived subgroups. If you haven’t, you shouldn’t be trying to read this paper.

Comment: My group theory is a little rusty so I didn't realized the isomorphism theorems are at use here. I think I have the knowledge I need to read this paper, but it's clear that I need to brush up on the background a bit before continuing.

Comment: My apologies if that sounded a bit harsh, but I've had some experience with computer science and/or optimization folks who know what a group is, and jump into reading papers on algoirthmic group theory and flounder at the theory because their group theory isn't at the required level. I'm glad to hear it is just a matter of lack of review, and I do encourage you to do a review of the isomorphism theorems, as well as basic results on solvable groups.